# How do you perform math on template variables in django 1.9

Tags: python, django

I have a variable `{{ counter }}` in a template coming from its corresponding view. In the view `counter = 0`. I would like to increment the value of `{{ counter }}`, or maybe do other manipulations. Can this be done? Examples welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could use a built-in [add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#add) template tag. do `{{ counter|add:"5" }}`. That way, if you had `counter == 3`, it'd return `8`.

It doesn't change the actual `counter` variable, but you shouldn't do it in the template nevertheless. 
If you need it when iterating over some objects, you could use a [for loop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for)'s `forloop.counter` instead:

```
<ul>
    {% for object in object_list %}
        <li> {{ forloop.counter }} {{ object }}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: afaik it does nto actually change counter however ... just the output ... but +1 good answer all the same

Comment: Is there any way to do something like {{ counter += 1 }}? I'd like to do that in a for loop so that I could increment say <h3>#{{ counter }}</h3> somewhere  else in the template.

Comment: @DarkNawg I've updated my answer; in short, you shouldn't do it in the template; you must use `forloop.counter` instead.